# Cannot install plugins via API

Tags: scmmanager

I am trying to install scm-activity-plugin & scm-webhook-plugin via API and is not working.
I try all possible options without success:

curl -k -s -u "user:pass" -X POST "https://my_custom_address/scm/api/rest/plugins/install/scm-activity-plugin/" -H "Content-Type: application/json"

curl -k -s -u "user:pass" -X POST "https://my_custom_address/scm/api/rest/plugins/install/scm-activity-plugin/" -H "Accept: application/json"

curl -k -s -u "user:pass" -X POST "https://my_custom_address/scm/api/rest/plugins/install/scm-activity-plugin"

The GET is working ok:
{
"artifactId": "scm-activity-plugin",
"author": "Sebastian Sdorra",
"category": null,
"condition": {
"arch": null,
"min-version": "1.32"
},
"description": "Shows the latest activity from your repositories.",
"groupId": "sonia.scm.plugins",
"name": "scm-activity-plugin",
"screenshots": [
"http://download.scm-manager.org/images/scm-activity-plugin/screenshot-1.png"
],
"state": "INSTALLED",
"url": "https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-activity-plugin",
"version": "1.12",
"wiki": null
},

Can somebody help me ? I am using version 1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the groupid and the version in the URL, too. Something like this should be working with version 1.60:

```
curl -u "user:pass" \
    http://localhost:8080/scm/api/rest/plugins/install/sonia.scm.plugins:scm-activity-plugin:1.12 \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -X POST
```

Comment: Thank you so much Rene , it works perfect ! To bad that is not written anywhere the pattern : /scm/api/rest/plugins/install//groupId:artifactId:version